How to set position of a button at a the edge of its parent container
can someone tell me how to position my button labeled as "View Details" on the edge of its parent container. I am using tailwind CSS.
I want to position my button at bottom edge of the card.
I have tried by giving the parent div's position as "relative" and button's position as 'absolute' and then by giving a bottom value to make it hang at the border line. But the output was not as expected, as shown in the above image the button is pushed behind the card making only half of it visible.
I have given the parent container position as follow:
className="first-card relative"

the View Details button's CSS as follow:
className="-bottom-6 left-[50%] translate-x-[-50%] absolute"
here is the code snippet:
import { Card, Button } from "@mui/material";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const openAddDialog = () => {
    // Handle button click
  };

  return (
    <Card
      className="first-card relative"
      sx={{
        borderRadius: "20px",
        paddingTop: "10px",
        height: "20%",
        marginBottom: "2%",
        position: "relative", // Ensure the card has relative positioning
      }}
      elevation={0}
    >
      {/* Other components */}
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        sx={{
          borderRadius: "50px", // Pill shape
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          color: "#0AE9D3",
          padding: "4px 16px", // Small size
          fontSize: "12px", // Small text
          marginBottom: "10px",
          fontFamily: "Poppins",
          fontWeight: 500,
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
          },
          width: "20%",
          position: "absolute", // Position absolutely
          bottom: "-9px", // Adjust bottom position
          left: "50%",
          transform: "translateX(-50%)", // Center horizontally
        }}
        onClick={openAddDialog}
      >
        View Details
      </Button>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;


We can not debug screenshots. Please provide a proper [mre], when asking this kind of question.

"as shown in the above image the button is pushed behind the card" - "behind the card" is probably not the correct way of phrasing it; this rather looks like you had overflow: hidden applied to the container.

@CBroe Thank you for your suggestion. I understand why you might think that overflow: hidden could be causing the issue, but I haven't applied any overflow properties to the container.

You can use bottom-0 to place an absolute element at the end of a relative element. You just have to make sure your card is relative.
<article class="relative h-96 bg-amber-200 w-1/2 mx-auto">
  <div class="absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 flex justify-center">
    <button class="rounded-full bg-sky-100 px-4 py-1">VIEW DETAILS</button>
  </div>
</article>

DEMO on Tailwind Play

Update

I have already tried using bottom-0 to position the button at the bottom of the card but it didn't work as expected.

I think absolute is overridden by mui's default styles, you can use !absolute to increase its priority.
But a better approach would be to not make changes to the style of mui's Button element. You can add a div element like I did before:
<Card className="relative" elevation={0}>
  <div className="absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 flex justify-center">
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      sx={{
        borderRadius: "50px", // Pill shape
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        color: "#0AE9D3",
        padding: "4px 16px", // Small size
        fontSize: "12px", // Small text
        fontFamily: "Poppins",
        fontWeight: 500,
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
        },
      }}
      onClick={openAddDialog}
    >
      View Details
    </Button>
  </div>
</Card>


Thank you for the suggestion. I have already tried using bottom-0 to position the button at the bottom of the card and ensured that the card has position: relative, but it didn't work as expected. Could there be other factors or styles affecting the positioning of the element that I should check for? Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

@vasistasharma It should be that some styles are overridden by mui. I just updated the answer for mui and you can check if it solves your problem.
